# How can I use Font Awesome in React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, font-awesome

How can I use Font Awesome in React js? If i use it in my project it didn't show up. This is my code:

```
import React ,{Component} from 'react'
import './category.css'
import axios from 'axios'
import Course from './courses/course.js'
import Searchfilter from './search/search.js'

class Category extends Component{
    state={
        category :[]
    }
    componentDidMount(){
        axios.get('data.json').then(res =>{this.setState({category:res.data.content})
    })
    }
    render(){
  return (
    <div className="category">
      
      <Course corses={this.state.category} />
    </div>
  )
}
}
export default Category;
```

Comment: You mean font awesome??

Comment: oh  right :D
 do you know how can i use it

Comment: Font Awesome has a [dedicated page](https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/using-with/react) to help you get a working implementation with React.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways.

It seems for me that the easiest one is to add the font awesome CDN link,
in your 'index.html'

And use Font awesome as you would do with normal HTML

Comment: and thats will allows me to take the icons with the same code on the font awsome site ?

Comment: Exactly. something like this: 
<i class="fas fa-address-book"></i>

Comment: but use className instead of class to avoid the warnings

Comment: it appears as an empty rectangle

Comment: Which icon you are trying to use?

Answer (score 0):

Add this (CDN link ) in the head of the index.html file :

```
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/f7b906a276.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

and start using the icons like normal html tags :

```
<i className="fas fa-tachometer-alt"></i>
```

Or you can install font awesome package from npm ,
I suggest to follow this tutorial from fontawesome website : [Font Awesome with react tutorial](https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/using-with/react)

Answer (score 0):

You can just add your CDN link in the HTML page and then use  it as you use it in your normal HTML  but remember here class attribute is not allowed,  you should use className.

You should have jsx code like `<i className="fast fa-home"></i>`